# will paginate missing FROM-clause entry when paginating over association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I work with rails 2.3.5, will_paginate-2.3.15 and postgress.
I have 2 belongs_to's to the same table.
If i first search on a attribute and then on the aliased table attribute then it throws an exception. If I reverse the order in the conditions it works...

```
class House
  belongs_to :owner, :class => "User"
  belogns_to :creator, :class => "User"
end

House.paginate(
  :page=>1, 
  :include=>[:creator, :owner], 
  :per_page=>20, 
  :conditions=>"houses.city ILIKE E'%new yo%' and owners_houses.architect ILIKE E'%tom%'")
```

raises

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "owners_houses",
```

in logs no joins in from clause

This works:

```
House.paginate(
  :page=>1, 
  :include=>[:creator, :owner], 
  :per_page=>20, 
  :conditions=>"owners_houses.architect ILIKE E'%tom%' and houses.city ILIKE E'%new yo%'")
```

Is this a bug in will_paginate? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Check the development.log for the Sql query generated for WORKING and NON WORKING statement